# Set animation for whole layout

Tags: android, android-animation

I have a `Relative Layout`, which contains some views that correspond to some metadata on an image. I have onTapListener for the image which works like this:

```
image.setOnPhotoTapListener(new OnPhotoTapListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPhotoTap(View view, float x, float y) {
                if (visible) {
                    //fade-out the contents of relative layout
                    visible = false;
                } else {
                    //fade-in the contents of relative layout
                    visible = true;
                }
            }
        });
```

What I want is, to fade-out the contents of relative layout if it is visible or fade-in the contents if it is not visible. I basically want to use alpha animation for these effects.

How do I write the animation function for the two cases? I am very new to Android animations, so any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You merely have to perform the animation on the entire View.

If you're supporting at least API 11 then it's even easier because you get to use ObjectAnimators (If you're supporting 10 or less than you can use [NineOldAndroids](http://nineoldandroids.com/)).

For Alpha animations, you first get your root view, then create an ObjectAnimator that points to the "alpha" property.

```
View root = findViewById(R.id.rootId);
ObjectAnimator fadeIn = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(root, "alpha", 0f, 1f);
fadeIn.setDuration(500);
ObjectAnimator fadeOut = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(root, "alpha", 1f, 0f);
fadeOut.setDuration(500);

// Whenever you want to fade in.
if (fadeOut.isRunning()) {
  fadeOut.cancel(); // Cancel the opposite animation if it is running or else you get funky looks
}
fadeIn.start();

// Whenever you want to fade out.
if (fadeIn.isRunning()) {
   fadeIn.cancel();
}
fadeOut.start();
```

`fadeIn` will animate the target (root) from 0 to 1 for 500 milliseconds. `fadeOut` will animate the target from 1 to 0 for 500 milliseconds.

Comment: can you suggest me which type of interpolator should I use for fade in and fade out?

Comment: @AmitTiwari  The default is linear. Another commonly used one is  DecelerateInterpolator. However, with these super-fast animations I can never tell the difference, though I'm not a designer ;). I would say just play around to see which one looks coolest.